# Strange MySQL behaviour with column named change

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to create a table with a column names "Change". Here's the code I used

```
$create=mysql_query("CREATE TABLE table_name (ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
Name TEXT ,Property TEXT ,Change TEXT ,Change_Percent TEXT ,Low_Look TEXT ,
High_Look TEXT ,Low_Proximity TEXT ,Time_Index TEXT ,carom TEXT ,qualification 
TEXT)");

// Execute query
if (mysql_query($con,$create))
  {
  echo "Table created successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating table: " . mysql_error($conn);
  }
```

This then gives me the following error

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in
C:\xampp\htdocs\stock\test.php on line 20
Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'Change TEXT ,Change_Percent TEXT ,Low_Look TEXT ,High_Look TEXT ,Low_Proximity TEXT '
at line 1
```

After trying a few things I noticed that taking of the "e" from Change solved the problem. Now what could be causing it, and is there a way to name a column "Change"? if it were to be absolutely necessary.

Comment: See the list: **[Reserved keywords in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)**

Comment: You can use backticks around change, but it's highly NOT encouraged to use reserved words

Comment: Thanks for the link @ypercube good to bookmark it for such times..

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change is a reserved word. You might try changing to another name or at least wrapping it in backticks.

Answer (score 1):

`change` is mysql keyword, use backtick (`)  "change"